# Best way to check the connection to my database js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, postgresql

I work on a web interface which receives and send informations to a distant PostGreSQL database.

From what I found on the internet it seems that the best way is to create a small php script in an external .php file.

I followed that idea,

so I have that script pg_connection.php  which tests the connectivity to my database (with a pg_connect) in that style :

```
$db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=**** user=**** password=****") 
or die("Not Connected");
if ($db) {echo (Connected);} else {echo (Not Connected);}
```

If I launch only that pg_connection.php in my webbrowser, it works fine (I just have wrotten Connected with the correct login infos entered in my script or Not connected if I put a random ip address).

Then in my .js(+jquery) external script I use :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#dbstatus").load("php-services/pg_connection.php");
var dbstatus = new String();
dbstatus = $("#dbstatus").val();

if (dbstatus == "Connected")
{ /*jquery code to show a green light on a section in my html page*/}
else { /*jquery code to show a red light*/}
}
```

And that works partially :

In my $("#dbstatus") object it will replace the default text by Connected or Not Connected,
But it doesn't produce any effect on the green/red light in my conditionnal

Then I went in my Chrome console and type dbstatus, and I realized that the content of my var is

```
<div id=​"dbstatus" class=​"span3">​Connected​</div>​
```

when I expected it to be just "Connected".

Any idea on how to clean that var from all these extra html stuffs ?

Is there more simple method implemented in js or Jquery to check a postgreSQL database status ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify your code to:

```
$db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=**** user=**** password=****") or die("0");
if ($db) {echo "1";} else {echo "0"}
```

And in JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://fullpathto/php-services/pg_connection.php",
    cache: false
  }).done(function( result ) {
    if(result=="1") {
      /*jquery code to show a green light on a section in my html page*/
    }
    else
    {
      /*jquery code to show a red light*/}
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It really does not matter what he sends. The problem is, that he captured HTML of loading div...

Comment: Maybe, but $.ajax seems a much reasonable way of querying than using an intermediate div, then reading that div content. Instead, you should just read the response of the AJAX call, and you will also have more control over complete(), error() etc... Also, using a form of 0/1 instead of "Connected / Not connected" allows for futura boolean evaluation in other parts of the code.

Comment: Thank you guys, It worked just fine, I used Connected/Not Connected instead of 0 and 1 to reuse the string in my interface. That $.ajax is magic.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$("#dbstatus").val();` use `$("#dbstatus").html();`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, and when I check in Chrome's console, for my var dbstatus, I still have
    <div id=​"dbstatus" class=​"span3">​Connected​</div>​